# Export a CREATE script for a database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Say I've created a database in pgAdmin, but I want to export a CREATE sql file.

How would I go about generating the dump?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Link gives 404.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To generate a sql script that will create the tables as they exist in a given database do:

`pg_dump --schema-only --no-owner the_database > create_the_tables.sql`

This will give you a bunch of create table statements. Just to see how portable it was I tried the above as follows:

```
bvm$ pg_dump -s --no-owner devdb | sqlite3 so_ans.db
```

And then:

```
bvm$ sqlite3 so_ans.db .schema
CREATE TABLE courses (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text,
    created_by integer,
    jc text
);
```

Kind of cool.

Comment: Does this output all objects, triggers, procedures, etc?

Comment: "pg_dump -U postgres --schema-only --no-owner documents > create_the_tables.sql", if the user is postgres and you are using Windows OS. Otherwise, it would use your Windows user account name by default.

Comment: The question was how to use pgAdmin not pg_dump.

Answer (score 190):

Here's how to use pgAdmin to create a schema script that can be used with a PostgreSql database schema comparison tool such as [apgdiff](http://www.apgdiff.com/). These instructions are for pgAdmin3.

1. In pgAdmin, right click on the database and click Backup.
2. Enter an appropriate path and filename (i.e. `/some/path/my_script.sql`).
3. Select Plain as the format in the format dropdown.
4. Go to the Dump **Options #1** tab and check "Only schema".
5. Then click Backup. Then click Done.

**Note:** Yes, I realize that pgAdmin uses pg_dump behind the scenes to create the script, but the question was about pgAdmin, so this is the GUI method.

Comment: Is this up to date? There's no backup option in the context menu when right clicking on a database. There's a backup option in the tools menu, but it's always disabled no mater what I have selected (database, schema, individual tables, etc). This is with pgAdmin 1.18.1 on Linux.

Comment: It turns out I just had to specify the Postgres binary path (where pg_dump is). This is done in the options of pgAdmin (File > Options > Binary paths and set the PG bin path). This is likely because I did not have a standalone Postgres client installed at the time that I installed pgAdmin.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, Two years after the NON pgadmin given.. So you get my upvote as its the valid answer for the OP's question

Comment: Three years later, still helpful

Comment: 4 years and counting.

Comment: Still up to date (pgAdmin4)

Comment: This should be accepted answer, still works in 2020 if wants to export schema using pgAdmin.

Comment: Nine years and counting. Super helpful answer.

Comment: Ten years milestone reached. Answer is still valid.

Answer (score 25):

pgAdmin however does have a facility to do what you want:

Right-click on the database you want to export

Select Backup from the pop-up menu

Choose "format" Plain.

Choose "plain option" Only schema

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this through phpPgAdmin just like phpMyAdmin for MySQL.

Login to phpPgAdmin select the database and then choose export.

Answer (score 1):

At least in PgAdmin III 1.22.1 you can get CREATE script doing:
1) right-click on table name
2) "Scripts" -> "CREATE script" 
There are options to get SELECT, DELETE etc.

Comment: I think this answer is interesting, but when I click on "Scripts" I can see only the "SELECT" option

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it works for me

Comment: This works, but probably not up-voted much because the original question is worded in a way that sounded like they were asking for a way to dump out a script for the whole db in one go, rather than do it individually table by table.