# I want to export a script for my database in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've created a database in pgAdmin, in which I've 1 public schema and 4 custom schema's. These schema contains several functions, sequences and Tables. Now I want to export a script that can create same database with the same structure without any data. Please help me with this....

Comment: Could you please show us your script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a CREATE script for a database from pgAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024108/export-a-create-script-for-a-database-from-pgadmin)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) with the (default) plain format.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access to the command line, type this

`pg_dump --create --clean --schema-only -U your_user -d db_name > file_name.sql`

Then in the server you need to create same database run this

```
psql -U db_user -d db_name < file_name.sql
```

`--clean` option tries to drop all objects before creating them.

`--create` Begin the output with a command to create the database itself and reconnect to the created database.